# What font can I use to recreate the logo for JP&R Advertising Agency?

Tags: font-identification

I'm trying to recreate (as close as possible, doesn't need to be exact) a logo with text, but am having trouble.  The reason I'm not just using the image is because it will be looped several hundred thousand times in a mailing app and introduces unnecessary overhead so I just want to use the closest possible text alternative.

I've tried the various font identifying sites (whatthefont, etc.) but it's to jumbled and Photoshoped to identify.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I'm taking a wild guess that the ampersand is probably custom...

Comment: I ran it through whatthefont [with the ampersand removed](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/results?ch%5B0%5D=J&ch%5B1%5D=P&ch%5B2%5D=R&wtfserver=wtf_e_41&id=0009894051d1b8890009d3de000031ad&glyphcount=3&imageid=0&x=57&y=35), but still no match:

Comment: @Dominic Yeah as long as I can get something close, I was thinking I might need to do the text in one font and the ampersand in a second font

Comment: @John yeah I gave that a shot no good I even tried to clean up the shadows and stuff around the lettering but to no avail

Comment: The whole thing looks rather custom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's close to [Akzidenz Grotesk Extended](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/berthold/akzidenz-grotesk-next/) with some distortions.

[image]